# Computation of the Differentials Using Smooth Curves

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, tangent-spaces

I attempt to understand the computation of the differential of a smooth map between two smooth manifolds using smooth curves from Loring Tu's *An Introduction to Manifolds* (Second Edition, page no. 95). The corresponding section of the book is given below. [image]

I understand the proof and can derive up to the following expression:
$$F_{*, p} \, (X_p) = (F \circ c)_{*,0} \left( \left.\frac{d}{dt}\right\vert_0 \right).$$

But I don't understand how we get the last line: $$\cdots = \left.\frac{d}{dt}\right\vert_0 (F \circ c)(t).$$

I proceeded as follows. As $F_{*, p} \, (X_p): C_{F(p)}^{\infty}(M) \to \mathbb{R}$ is a derivation at the point $F(p) \in M$, I choose an element $[f]_{F(p)}$ of of the algebra $C_{F(p)}^{\infty}(M)$ and compute the followings.

$$\left(F_{*, p} \, (X_p)\right)(f) =  \left( (F \circ c)_{*,0} \left( \left.\frac{d}{dt}\right\vert_0 \right)\right)(f) = \left.\frac{d}{dt}\right\vert_0 (f \circ F \circ c)(t),$$
where in the last step I have used the definition of a differential of a smooth function between two smooth manifolds.

Now I am not sure how to proceed any further to get the desired expression in the last line of the book.

Comment: Basically, if $X$ is represented by the curve $c$, then $F_*X$ is represented by the curve $F\circ c$.

Comment: Just think about the last expression and break it down: $\left. \frac{d}{dt} \right|_{0} (f \circ F \circ c)(t)$. It is the $t$-derivative of $f$ as you move along the curve $F \circ c$. So...what is the vector field whose action on $f$ is to take the $t$-derivative along the curve? The velocity vector!